# nginx: no handler for server

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to configure nginx proxy for a tcp service, the http proxy stuff works as expected. However, I keep getting this error for the server inside the `stream` context.

`no handler for server in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:6`

I don't understand how it's different from the servers defined in the `http` context.

```
events {

}

stream {
      server {
        listen 5601;
        deny   all;
    }
}

http {

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root /var/www/certbot;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://example.com:5601;
        }
    }
}
```

What does this error mean and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
listen 5601;
deny   all;
```

The `listen` dont understand, **what will I am to do for listen here?**
Immediately it found a `deny all;`. **what will I am doing with deny?**.
So you must tell the `listen` to what to do it stand for. For ex:

```
listen 853;
proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:53;
```

Here, I ordered `listen` to do something. So it know what to do it stand for. It was there to listen on port 853 and then proxying to localhost. Ya, somethink like that.
Dont forget to restart

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx.services
```

You said:

> I don't understand how it's different from the servers defined in the http context.

Sure. Because `server` on `http` know what to do after listen. :)